# How to prevent status messages in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, statusbar

Here, as an example, while Chrome is trying to connect to a video stream, a status message is shown in the lower left hand corner:

[image: Annotated screenshot of message popping up]

*How do I avoid that?*

This is for running a web site on a kiosk. I do have full control over the web site source code. However, I assume this is something that has to be changed, if that is possible at all, in the browser settings somewhere.